# Understanding behaviour of scikit-image filter gaussian

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am exploring the segmentation of objects in an image using scikit-image in python. One of the functions I would like to use is filters.gaussian, with the end goal doing a Hysteresis thresholding. I would like to understand the behaviour of the blur function a bit better.

**The code is as follows:**

```
import numpy
import os
import cv2
from skimage import filters

### Change into dir ###
dir = r'C:\Path\To\Image'
file_name = r'Image.png'
os.chdir(dir)

### Load image and print highest and lowest values ###
image = cv2.imread(file_name, 0) 
lower = numpy.amin(image)
upper = numpy.amax(image)
print(lower)
print(upper)

### Apply gaussian blur and print highest and lowest values post filter ###
gaus = filters.gaussian(image, sigma=3)
lower = numpy.amin(gaus)
upper = numpy.amax(gaus)
print(lower)
print(upper)
```

The output for the image is:

- low = 0
- high = 103

The output for the blurred image:

- low = 0.0
- high = 0.39462399113380187

**My question is twofold:**

1. Why does the range of my values change when applying a gaussian blur?
2. And more importantly, will this cause any issues when doing e.g. Hysteresis thresholding?

**My workspace:**

- Python 3.10.0
- scikit-image 0.18.3

Answer (score 0):

1. `filters.gaussian()` will return a range between [0-1], if you want to keep original range use argument: `preserve_range` [docs link for deeper answer](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.filters.html?msclkid=23e1ede0a6a911ecb3ee18b2605488da#skimage.filters.gaussian)
2. As the normalization of the range is a built in feature, it's will very probably not have a impact on other process especially if you don't modify the range manually